# jquery tablesorter with accounting number format

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery tablesorter and I'm trying to sort a column with values similar to this:

$100,000
 $38,000
 ($4,000)
  $2,000

Data within () are negative numbers.  When using the default sort feature, it does not recognize the ($4,000) as a negative number, so I'm trying to create a custom function to handle this.

The solution below is what I have come up with, and it works fine.  But I'm wondering if there is a better solution?  I'm new to jquery and just looking for some insight.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $.tablesorter.addParser({
                // set a unique id
                id: 'currency-column',
                is: function(s) {
                        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
                        return false;
                },
                format: function(s) {
                         s = s.replace(/$/g,"");
                         s = s.replace(/\(/g,"-");
                         s = s.replace(/\)/g,"");
                         return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9.-]/g),""));
                },

                type: 'numeric'
        });

        $("#myTable").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                3: { sorter:'currency-column' },
                4: { sorter:'currency-column' },
                5: { sorter:'currency-column' },
                6: { sorter:'currency-column' },
                7: { sorter: false },
                10: { sorter:'currency-column' }
            }
        }); 

    } 
);
```

Again, it does what is required and I'm satisfied with the results (and maybe I should just leave it there...), but if there is a better solution I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the way you used, I did a search an the only alternative I found was to have a hidden column with the unformatted values as float values and sort by that

Answer (score 2):

How abour removing ","

```
s = s.replace(/,/g,"");
```

so, your function become:

```
format: function(s) {
         s = s.replace(/$/g,"");
         s = s.replace(/\(/g,"-");
         s = s.replace(/\)/g,"");
         s = s.replace(/,/g,"");
         return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9.-]/g),""));
},
```

^.^